# How to create a partition on a shrunk LVM volume

Tags: linux, partitioning, lvm

I have a Linux LVM volume that is about 400 GB.
I have shrunk it to 200 GB to get some space for a new NTFS partition on which I can install Win7.

```
umount /local
e2fsck -f /dev/mapper/vg00-lvol2
resize2fs /dev/mapper/vg00-lvol2 217G
lvresize -L 217G /dev/mapper/vg00-lvol2
lvdisplay /dev/mapper/vg00-lvol2
mount /local
```

I have now about 200 GB of free space in the LVM volume.

```
-->lvm pvs
  PV         VG   Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree  
  /dev/sda3  vg00 lvm2 a--  465.16G 213.00G
```

How can I create an NTFS partition on that free space? I'm guessing I'll need something on the lines of:

1. Logical LVM volume on that free space: `lvcreate vg00 -l100%FREE`
2. Physical LVM volume on that logical volume.
3. LVM volume group on that physical volume.
4. mkfs on the LVM volume grooup.

Answer (score 0):

The only things you need to do are steps 1 and 4 to create a new filesystem using the remaining space.

HOWEVER: **Windows can't read LVM partitions**: it's a format that Windows doesn't understand.  You can use Linux to create an NTFS filesystem on it if you want but Windows will never be able to see it.

What you actually need to do is resize the physical volume.  I'd recommend using something like gparted which makes it relatively simple (always have backups!).  Then you'll create a new primary or secondary partition on the disk using the free space.